# Reuse function Angular 1

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Let's say I have `2 lists of items`: available items and associated items.
now I want to write a search function that calls API methods that do the search for each list `(different methods)`.
I want to sign the search results into models using `$scope object`.
Like this:

```
 $scope.availableItems.data = response.data;
```

What is the best way to write a reusable search method in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your search methods into a service, inject the service into your components. Bind to the values in the service, or better, create a getter in your components and return the value from the injected service.

Something like:

In your service:

this.searchVal = '';

```
executeSearch ( searchTerm ) {
   // The usual http angular stuff etc.
   .then ( function ( d ) {
      this.searchVal = d; // however you do it in your code
   }
}
```

In your components, into which you inject your searchService:

```
function getSearchValue ( ) {
   return myInjectedService.searchVal;
}
```

In your component templates, bind to the getter, say you put the getSearchValue on the scope:

```
{{getSearchValue()}}
```